# Get power bi dataset tables (Automate)

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powerbi-api

I'm trying to find a way to get power bi dataset tables (Automated way). I tried using Powershell rest API:

```
$tablesUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/$datasetId/tables"

# Invoke the REST API to get dataset tables
$tablesResponse = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $tablesUrl -Method GET
$tables = $tablesResponse.value

# Process the retrieved tables
foreach ($table in $tables) {
   Write-Host "Table Name: $($table.name)"
   # Add any additional logic to process the table information as needed
}
```

But it's only working with the push dataset. Is there another way?

Comment: Check the [scanner API](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-scanner-api-admin-rest-apis-enhancements-to-include-dataset-tables-columns-measures-dax-expressions-and-mashup-queries/)